# Controller action not receiving parameter from view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm developing a small project in C# ASP.NET MVC. My problem is I have a View which presents the user a table with all the Stock. The HTML code is presented below:

```
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Item Id</th>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Unit Price (€)</th>
            <th>Stand</th>
            <th>Available Quantity</th>
            <th>Operation</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (StockViewModel stock in Model.Stock)
        {
         <tr>
             <td>@stock.Item_Id</td>
             <td>@stock.Brand</td>
             <td>@stock.Model</td>
             <td>@stock.Unit_Price</td>
             <td>@stock.Stand_Id</td>
             <td>@stock.Available_Quantity</td>
             <td><a href="~/Stock/UpdateStock/@stock.Item_Id">Update</a> | Delete</td>
         </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

The problem is the value of the Item_Id is arriving empty in the controller:

```
    public ActionResult UpdateStock(string i)
    {
        StockViewModel stock = new StockViewModel();
        stock.Item_Id = i;
        return View("UpdateStock", stock); 
    }
```

I already searched for small tutorials on the Internet and they always perform this kind of operations, but mine isn't working. Do you know what I'm missing?

Comment: How does your route pattern looks like?

Comment: @MikeSW are you referring to the URL? Sorry for my lack of knowledge! If Yes, it goes as  http://localhost:64734/Stock/UpdateStock/1 in the case I try to update the first item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how you have your routes set up, it's impossible to tell - but I'd be willing to bet that you haven't changed the default routes. If that's the case, you can fix this problem by changing `UpdateStock(string i)` to `UpdateStock(string id)`.

Check out your RouteConfig.cs and look at your default route. The parameter name it expects is `id`, and will automatically bind it to whatever follows the "/" on an action. If you need to stick with the variable `i`, you can do the following:

```
<td><a href="~/Stock/UpdateStock?i=@stock.Item_Id">Update</a> | Delete</td>
```

Unless you want to [create a custom route](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/299531/Custom-routes-for-MVC-Application), you'll have to build a query string for parameters named anything other than `id`.

You may also be interested in looking into [Razor's ActionLink HTML Helper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068(v=vs.118).aspx), which can be very beneficial when it comes to avoiding typos while creating links.